# Java: How to drag a file from a JTable to native filesystem?

Tags: java, swing, file, drag-and-drop, jtable

My Java 7 Swing application features a JTable that contains the following objects:

```
public class MyFile {

    private long id;
    private long created;
    private long modified;
    private String description;
    private File file;

    public MyFile(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.created = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // getter & setter methods ...

}
```

The goal is to drag these *MyFile* objects out of my application and drop them to the filesystem (e.g. to the desktop). When setting *setDragEnabled(true)* to my JTable, the icon already turns to a "+" symbol when dragging a table entry, as known by regular drag&drop actions from other applications. But when actually dropping the object to the desktop nothing happens...

How can I tell my JTable to only drop the *File* object inside the *MyFile* object ? Did I forgot more things ?

Could someone provide a short sample ?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure your table with the following properties:

```
tblDocuments.setDragEnabled(true);
tblDocuments.setTransferHandler(new FileTransferHandler());
```

Here's the TransferHandler implementation:

```
public class FileTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        // copy your files from the component to a concrete List<File> files ...
        // the following code would be a sample for a JList filled with java.io.File(s) ...
        /*JList list = (JList) c;
        for (Object obj: list.getSelectedValues()) {
            files.add((File)obj);
        }*/
        return new FileTransferable(files);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return MOVE;
    }
}
```

Here's the FileTransferable implementation:

```
public class FileTransferable implements Transferable {

    private List<File> files;

    public FileTransferable(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[]{DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor};
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must make sure that the created `Transferable` contains the [`DataFlavor#javaFileListFlavor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor) and that the data for that flavor is the `File` contained in your `MyFile` instance (to be more precise: a `List` with the `File`, as explained in the javadoc of that flavor).

This will probably require a custom `TransferHandler` on your `JTable`.

Comment: I'm doubt..., maybe in the case that File isn't stored in XxxTableModel

Comment: Could you provide some more information, a short how-to or even a sample :-) ?